# how to query for key exists in object field in firestore document (firebase web sdk)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have **subjects** collection. In this collection every document has **tutors** field that is object where key is id of tutors( from tutors collection)

```
tutors: {
  "tutor_id_1": {
    "name": "jonas",
    "email": "jonas@gmail.com"
  },
  "tutor_id_2":{
   "name": "stephen",
   "email": "stephen@gmail.com"
 },
 "tutor_id_3":{
  "name": "maria",
  "email":"maria@gmail.com"
 }
}
```

So how to query subjects where tutors field contain tutor id equal to "tutor_id_1" ?

I found one way
if I have two variables in client side
const tutorToFindId = "xxx"
const tutorToFindEmail = "YYY"

```
query(
  collection(db, 'subjects'),
   where(`tutors.${tutorToFindId}.email`, '==', `${tutorToFindEmail}`)
),
```

**Is there any other way ??**

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, "tutor_id_1" is being used as a unique id. Considering that, you may structure your data model with "tutors" as a [subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#subcollections) instead of a field and you will be able to [get the content of that specific document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) as follows:

```
const docRef = db.collection('subjects').doc('subjectX').collection('tutors').doc(tutorToFindId);
 
const tutor = await docRef.get();

if (!tutor.exists) {
   console.log('No such document!');
} else {
   console.log('Document data:', tutor.data());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getBy({ where: { [`tutors.${tutorToFindId}.email`]: tutorToFindEmail } });
```

Take a look at the `getBy` function in https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-firestore-helper

Disclaimer: I am the creator of this library. It helps to manipulate objects in Firebase Firestore (and adds Cache)

Enjoy!